# Binary Quadratic Forms of Discriminant -3

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

The following is a question in my textbook:

Show that any positive definite binary quadratic form of discriminant $-3$ is equivalent to $f(x, y) = x^2 + xy + y^2$. 
Show that a positive integer $n$ is properly represented by $f$ if and only if $n$ is of the form $n = 3^\alpha \prod p^\beta$, where $\alpha = 0$ or $1$ and all primes are of the form $3k + 1$.
Show that for $n$ of this form, the number of proper representations is $6 \cdot 2^s$ where $s$ is the number of distinct primes $p = 1 \mod 3$ that divide $n$.

However, I have no idea where to begin. It was mentioned that we could use Eisenstein integers like Gaussian integers in the similar proof of binary quadratic forms of discriminant -3, but I'm still stuck.

I know how to prove the first statement.

Comment: Do you know about *reduced* forms?

Comment: @Lord yes, to the extent that they form equivalence classes, and that every quadratic binary form can be reduced to them. But I'm not sure how to show that every binary quadratic form of discriminant -3 is in the same equivalence class?

Comment: It's quite straightforward to show that $x^2+xy+y^2$ is the only reduced form of discriminant $-3$.

Comment: @Lord oh wait, you're right. I forgot about that

Comment: And now you can use Eisenstein integers....